# Parameterize Test in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have an `ExceptionTest` class where I store the Tests for each of the classes. I have quite a few methods where I am repeating the same structure.

```
public class ExceptionTest {
    
    @Test
    void conversionException() {
        assertThrows(ConversionException.class, () -> {
            try {
                throw new ConversionException();
            } catch (QOException ex) {
                assertEquals("Error converting", ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(417 /* FAILED */, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(ErrorCodes.DOCUMENT_ERROR, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Test
    void userException() {
        assertThrows(UserException.class, () -> {
            try {
                Integer maxUsers = 5;
                throw new UserException(maxUsers);
            } catch (QOException ex) {
                Integer maxUsers = 5;
                assertEquals("Excedido "+ maxUsers +" disp", ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(403 /* FORBIDDEN */, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(ErrorCodes.USERS, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From what I have read in `Spring` you can use the `@ParameterizedTest` annotation in a separate class and call that class from each Test method, and collect it from the method parameterized with the `@MethodSource` annotation.

This is the code I am looking for:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("stringProvider")
void testWithExplicitLocalMethodSource(String argument) {
    assertNotNull(argument);
}
```

The problem is that I do not apply it to the classes I have in Test. How do I have to create the `method` in a separate class to apply the structure to all the Tests that are in the `ExceptionTest` class?

Comment: what exactly do you want to parameterize for your tests?

Comment: The structure in all is the same, what changes is the data, I don't know if there is a way to parameterize that or is it possible in this case

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems familiar to an article posted by Baeldung.com; where they gave this as example:

```
class StringsUnitTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("com.baeldung.parameterized.StringParams#blankStrings")
    void isBlank_ShouldReturnTrueForNullOrBlankStringsExternalSource(String input) {
        assertTrue(Strings.isBlank(input));
    }
}

public class StringParams {

    static Stream<String> blankStrings() {
        return Stream.of(null, "", "  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's what I'm seeing, what I don't know is how to apply it to my code